# Ruby enumerable select with optional limit / find

Tags: ruby, haml, middleman

I have the following enumerable to select articles based on a category (HAML)

```
- blog( ENV[ "site" ] ).articles.select { | a | a.data[ :category ] == category }.each_with_index do | article, index |
= index
```

I want to be able to limit this call but optionally, i.e. return 2 or maybe return all

```
- blog( ENV[ "site" ] ).articles.select { | a | a.data[ :category ] == category }.first( 2 ).each_with_index do | article, index |
= index
```

i.e. with the introduction of first( 2 )

But optionally doing something like first( 'all' ) or first( ) is not possible

Thanks

Comment: You shouldn't be cramming this much logic into your view. You could use a scope/method on your model to handle the `select` portion, and a helper to handle the conditional logic of `first(2)`/`all`. Note that `first('all')` makes no sense, if you want `all` then just omit the `.first` call.

Comment: @meagar is right. What is `blog(...)`? Is `articles` a an ActiveRecord relation? There probably are much cleaner ways to achieve what you want, without defining a single new method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def some_meth(data, option)
  raise 'Invalid option' if !option.is_a?(Integer) || option != 'all'

  option == 'all' ? data : data.first(option)
end
```

Usage:

```
- some_meth(blog( ENV[ "site" ] ).articles.select { | a | a.data[ :category ] == category }, 2)
```

or

```
- some_meth(blog( ENV[ "site" ] ).articles.select { | a | a.data[ :category ] == category }, 'all')
```